# How to remove warning: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value?

Tags: c, casting

I have a  `char buf[3];` array where I need to put: `buf[0] = ch` where `ch` is an `int`. But the compiler give the following warning:

> conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value

How do I remove this? I tried cast to `unsigned char` but no luck.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I couldn't reproduce the warning on gcc 4.6.3 even after setting the -Wall flag.

Comment: gcc version 4.6.2. You need to use `-Wconversion`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an explicit cast:

```
buf[0] = (char)ch;
```

Comment: @Jack: only if the value in `ch` is not representable as a `char`.

Comment: Thanks. What about do I use `signed char` instead of? it solves the warning and can represent non-representable `char`.

Comment: @Jack: `char` is signed by default.

Comment: @sfstewman: no, the signedness of char is compiler-dependent - you need to specify `signed char` if you want to guarantee a signed quantity.

Comment: @PaulR: you're correct.  Why wouldn't the standard just specify the signedness of it?

Comment: @Jack: `sizeof(signed char) == sizeof(char) == sizeof(unsigned char) <= sizeof(int)`.  Casting to any form of `char` may truncate your `int`.  If you're worried about this, you can test the value after casting: `if (buf[0] != ch) { /* handle truncation */ }`.

Comment: @sfstewman: Casting a non-representable value to `char` can crash your program ("..or an implementation-defined signal is raised").

Comment: @undur_gongor: So what you (and 6.3.1.3 of C99) are saying is: casting an `int` to a `signed char` is not portable/safe if the magnitude of the `int` is too large, so either pre-test the value with `if ((ch < SCHAR_MIN) | (ch > SCHAR_MAX)) { /* handle under-/overflow */ }`, or declare `buf` to be `unsigned char` and post-test if the value is equal.

Comment: @sfstweman The standard was created based on the behavior of existing compilers that predated it.  Some used signed chars, others unsigned.  C was designed, implemented, reimplemented by others, and only then standardized.

Answer (score 5):

A char is one byte long while an integer is generally 4 bytes (implementation defined).
If you try to cast an integer to char, obviously you'll loose upper three bytes.

You can do so by `buf[0]=(char)ch`, if you are sure that your int is not longer than 1 byte. Otherwise there is a loss of information.